# How can one feed stuff into a script's stdin while in the debugger interface?

Tags: node.js, debugging, stdin

I've run:

```
node debug f.js
```

And now I have a:

```
debug>
```

prompt. How can I toggle between the stuff I type into the terminal being interpreted as debug commands and it being fed to the script's stdin?

Comment: did you find an answer to this in the interim?

Comment: I have the same problem. I didn't understand. It makes more sense now - REPL takes hold of stdin. But what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging programs that read from `stdin` is vastly easier after the inclusion of `inspector` to node core in version 8+.

1. Run the program via: `node --inspect-brk f.js`
2. Open Chrome.
3. Open chrome://inspect
4. Click "Open dedicated DevTools for Node"

This will separate the debugger input out to a "remote" debugger allowing you to continue sending input into your program from command line.

I pulled the steps from this [fantastic blog by Paul Irish](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)

Comment: Could you also answer the actual question, how to get the data from `stdin` in Chrome?

Comment: thank you. it worked. just run command like ` type "test.md" |  node  --inspect-brk    cli.js ` and open chrome

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, you can add a new Debug Configuration file with the property "console" set to "integratedTerminal".

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js",
  "console": "integratedTerminal"
}]
```

So now you can type into the terminal and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

per the nodejs docs,

> Running this program from the command line will start a REPL on stdin

which means if your app requires stdin, instead you must start a repl against the process through another means.  See https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

I found that using ms visual studio code or node-inspector met my needs

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and read the question on Stackoverflow a couple of weeks ago.

I didn't like any of the answers, because I really like text mode debugging; it works much better with my personal workflow.  So I forked the debugger and hooked up standard in.  If you want to use my fork, you can feed stdin in to the process either a few characters at a time with the `send()` command, you feed a whole file to it with `sendFile()`, or you can temporarily suspend the REPL with `ctty` and interact with the attached process' stdin directly.  The `ctty` command is good enough to operate a REPL itself.

I've called my fork `niim` (Node-Inspect IMproved) and have started making a laundry list of other things that I'd like to fix as well.

`npm i --global niim`

Full Disclosure: I am the originator of this node-inspect fork.